# moving empty cells in 2D cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

Is it possible to move the null entries to the end in a 2D cell array? E.g. if cell (2,2) was a `[]`, cell (3,2) would go in (2,2)'s place, (4,2) in (3,2) etc. and the nulls would be appended in the final row for example.

[image: here]

Comment: The cell array still has to be "rectangular" so you can easily delete and entire row or column but you can't delete a single cell. Do you just want to move all the empty cells to the end of their respective rows?

Comment: but then your cell structure will change, you will have to zero pad it at the end, it is better to move the [] to the last row/column of your cell structure instead of deleting them

Comment: you are right! I edited the post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C = {1 []; [] 4; 'aa' []}; %// example cell array
e = cellfun('isempty', C); %// this indicates for each cell if it's empty or not
[~, r] = sort(e, 1); %// sorting of each col to move empty cells to the end
[m, n] = size(C);
C = C(bsxfun(@plus, r, (0:m:m*(n-1)))); %// apply sorting to each col, using linear indexing
```

In this example, `C` is initially

```
C = 
    [ 1]     []
      []    [4]
    'aa'     []
```

and becomes

```
C = 
    [ 1]    [4]
    'aa'     []
      []     []
```

Some remarks:

- This works because [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) is *stable*: it preserves original order in case of ties. Note that `e` contains just zeros and ones.
- [Linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) is done efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). ([`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) could be used instead.)

Comment: great answer! Very efficient as well

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks!

Comment: :O awesome! that was exactly what I wanted! Many thanks! :)